# What is the domain of the function $f(x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{8(3)^{x-2}}{1-3^{2(x-1)}}\right)$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inequality

> What is the domain of the function
>   $f(x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{8(3)^{x-2}}{1-3^{2(x-1)}}\right)$?

I started using the fact  $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le f(x) \le \frac{\pi}{2}\implies-1 \le\frac{8(3)^{x-2}}{1-3^{2(x-1)}}\le1$.Now,on dissecting it into two  cases.

$CASE (1): -1 \le\frac{8(3)^{x-2}}{1-3^{2(x-1)}}$

$CASE (2): \frac{8(3)^{x-2}}{1-3^{2(x-1)}}\le1$

The calculations is inboth cases are bewidering,that's why i'm not showing it.

I need someone who can help me in solving this.

Comment: Use `$\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$` for $\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$ instead of `$(\frac{A}{B})$` for $(\frac{A}{B})$

Comment: Note that the domain is for most $x\in \Bbb C$ as the inverse sign can [output complex numbers](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcSin/04/01/) outside the real domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Step1 : Write the first case as $$-1\le \frac {\frac 83 \cdot t}{1-t^2}$$

Step 2: And second case as $$ \frac {\frac 83 \cdot t}{1-t^2}\le 1$$

Where $t=3^{x-1}$ and hence

Step 3: $t\ge 0$

Now you can take intersection of the intervals obtained from 3 above steps to get domain of $t$ and Resubstitute it in form of $x$ to get original domain

Comment: :Proceeding  your work  further i get $t\in [0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup [3,\infty)\implies 3^{x-1} \in [0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup [3,\infty)\implies (x-1)\in (-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty)\implies x\in (-\infty,0]\cup [2,\infty)$

Comment: @PKStyles, That is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Examine that,

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{8(3)^{x-2}}{1-3^{2(x-1)}}=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{8(3)^{x-2}}{1-3^{2(x-1)}}=0$$

Also the function is discontinuous at $x=1$.

Now check where it assumes the values $1$ and $-1$.

$$\frac{8(3)^{x-2}}{1-3^{2(x-1)}}=1$$

$$8(3)^{x-2}=1-3^{2(x-1)}$$

$$8(3)^{x-2}+3^{2(x-1)}=1$$

$$3^{x-1}(\frac{8}{3}+3^{x-1})=1$$

Let $3^{x-1}=t$

$$t(8+3t)=3$$

$$t=\frac{1}{3} \implies x=0 $$

---

$$\frac{8(3)^{x-2}}{1-3^{2(x-1)}}=-1$$

$$8(3)^{x-2}=-1+3^{2(x-1)}$$

$$8(3)^{x-2}-3^{2(x-1)}=-1$$

$$3^{x-1}(\frac{8}{3}-3^{x-1})=-1$$

Let $3^{x-1}=t$

$$t(8-3t)=-3$$

$$t=3 \implies x=2 $$

---

Therefore, Domain is, $$(-\infty,0]\cup[2,\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $3^{x-2}=a\implies a>0$ for real $x$

$$-1\le\dfrac{8a}{1-9a^2}\le1$$

$$\dfrac{8a}{1-9a^2}\le1\iff0\le\dfrac{9a^2+8a-1}{9a^2-1}=\dfrac{(9a-1)(a+1)}{(3a-1)(3a+1)}$$

As $a.0,$ we need $\dfrac{9a-1}{3a-1}\ge0$

$\implies$ either $9a-1=0\iff a=?$ or $ a>$max$\left(\dfrac19,\dfrac13\right)$ or $a<$min$\left(\dfrac19,\dfrac13\right)$

$\implies x<-2$ or $x\ge-1$

Similarly for $$-1\le\dfrac{8a}{1-9a^2}\iff\dfrac{8a+1-9a^2}{1-9a^2}\ge0$$

$$\iff\dfrac{(9a+1)(a-1)}{(3a+1)(3a-1)}\le0$$

As $a.0,$ we need $\dfrac{a-1}{3a-1}\ge0$

Can you take it from here?